# Most efficient way to compare datetime to varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, varchar

I'm working with a third party Microsoft SQL Server database, where most dates are saved as `varchar` columns in the format `yyyy_MM_dd hh:mm:ss.SSS`. In a lot of reports I need to select a specific time frame defined by two datetime variables. I'm using the following statement:

```
where cast(replace(a.somedate,'_','-') as datetime) between @begin and @end
```

I noticed that with this statement the query gets expensive fast when a lot of records need to be processed. What's the most efficient way to compare a varchar to a datetime?

Comment: Can't you fix the database so the dates are stored correctly?

Comment: I agree with @DavidG and if you can fix this problem at the source, that is probably the best way to go long term.

Comment: what about you create a persisted computed fields? in case if the system that feeding the database still running?

Comment: In this case, you could specify a similarly formatted varchar value for `@begin and @end`. It would be better to fix the schema to store as `datetime` or `datetime2(0)`.

Comment: Changing the db to solve this would be my preferred approach as well, but it belongs to proprietary third party software, so I'm not allowed to make changes to it.

Comment: OK, so if you can't change it, the format you have will sort in the same order as if you did it alphabetically, so you can simply provide your variables in text format instead.

Comment: To add to what @DanGuzman said, if there is an index on `somedate`, `where somedate >= '2000_01_01 00:00:00.000' and somedate < '2001_01_01 00:00:00.000'` should give you an index seek, courtesy of ISO dates being comparable by lexical ordering. If there is no index and you can't add one, there is little point to optimizing the operation in either direction, since the comparison isn't the bottleneck -- scanning all the individual rows is.

Comment: If you can't change the source, then I'd suggest speaking to your software vendors support team, and discussing with them. A **good** software vendor **should** know how to properly store data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a vendor application and you don't have control over the schema, you can refactor the `WHERE clause` as below for a sargable expression. This will allow an index on `somedateas` to be used efficiently. For example:

```
WHERE a.somedateas BETWEEN REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(19), @begin, 120), '-', '_') AND REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(19), @end, 120), '-', '_')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Except I used varchar(23) to get the entire datetime.